# Error handling jQuery AJAX promises with Q

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, promise, q

I'm using jQuery for AJAX but Q elsewhere in our application so want to ensure that the Promise implementation is consistent.

I've wrapped the jQuery AJAX call with Q like so:

```
Q($.ajax(url, {
  type: 'get'
}));
```

And it works all fine for success responses. Now I want to add error handling, I want to have global error handling (since we have a consistent error response from our server), making an API like so:

```
var xhr = function (url) {
    return Q($.ajax(url, {
      type: 'get'
    }))
    .then(function (data) {
      return data;
    }, function (res) {
      //global error handling
    });
};
```

And I'd expect to use it like this:

```
xhr('...').then(function () { console.log('success'); });
```

The problem is when the global error handler runs the "success" method on the consumer of the `xhr` method is invoked.

How would you prevent that?

A runnable sample can be seen here - http://jsbin.com/gudifu/3/edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Promise's second .then() not failing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23943322/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

Due to jQuery's non-standard promises, you have to jump through hoops to pass on the error to a Q-coerced promise.

Firtly, jqXHR's error signature is `(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`, and you typically want to pass on the second arg, `textStatus`.

Secondly, the two promise implementations are quite different with regard to error handling:

- **jQuery**: propagates the error state unless a fresh, resolved promise is returned from a `.then()` error callback. `.fail()` is guaranteed to propagate the error state regardless of what is returned. An uncaught `throw` will terminate the event thread.
- **Q**: marks an error as "handled" (ie send it down the success path) unless a `.catch()`, `.fail()` or `.then()` error callback rethows the error or throws a fresh one, in which case the promise continues down the error path.

Hence, you need to :

- chain `.then(null, errHandler)` to your `jQuery.ajax()` call in order to report `textStatus`
- throw an error from Q based on the jQuery error

```
var xhr = function (url) {
    return Q($.ajax(url, {
      type: 'get'
    }).then(null, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return textStatus;
    })).then(function (data) {
        return data;
    }, function (textStatus) {
      //global error handling
      throw new Error(textStatus);
    });
};
```

You could alternatively throw a proper error from jQuery and simply rethrow it from Q.

```
var xhr = function (url) {
    return Q($.ajax(url, {
      type: 'get'
    }).then(null, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return new Error(textStatus);
    })).then(function (data) {
        return data;
    }, function (err) {
      //global error handling
      throw err;
    });
};
```

The nett effect of the two solutions will be pretty close to identical. I think I'm right in saying that they will show a different error line number if the error was logged - the former stemming from Q and the latter stemming from jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the global error handler *handles* the error. As promises chain, your `xhr(…)` promise will just be *fulfilled* with whatever the error handler returned. It's like a `catch`, when an exception has been handled then normal execution resumes.

So you need to rethrow the exception from the handler so that the resulting promise gets rejected as well:

```
var xhr = function (url) {
    return Q($.ajax(url, {
        type: 'get'
    }))
    .then(null, function (res) {
        //global error handling
        throw res;
    });
};
```

Comment: Appear to return same result at jsbin ? Is function being called twice ?

Comment: Yes. Appear to be called on `console` at "runner-*" piece ? `:1
fail runner-3.25.21.min.js:1
pass through fail `  ? Will try at stacksnippets, jsfiddle

Comment: @guest271314: I have no idea what you're talking about. OP's version logs `fail - pass through success` while mine logs `fail - pass through fail` as expected.

Comment: Yes, appear did not interpret question correctly here . Read , viewed piece at OP and would have expected only single error response was, or should be desired returned result , reason . Re-read your answer and noticed "global error handler"