# $q.defer() then of the then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I didn't understand the behavior of the return value of `then` ,

Here its [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)  -

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of
>   when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one
>   of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result
>   is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the
>   result or rejection reason.

So let's try it , according to the follow little code section -

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.reject();
deferred.promise.then(function () {
        console.log("1st resolove");
    },
    function () {
        console.log("1st reject");
    }
).then(function () {
    console.log("2nd resolve");
    },
    function () {
        console.log("2nd reject");
    }
);
```

1) Why does it log -

```
1st reject
2nd resolve
```

instead of -

```
1st reject
2nd reject
```

?

2) What do I have to change to make it log -

```
1st reject
2nd reject
```

?

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []).
  controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$q){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   //deferred.resolve();
   deferred.reject();
   deferred.promise.then(function () {
     console.log("1st resolove");
    },
    function () {
     console.log("1st reject");
    }
   ).then(function () {
    console.log("2nd resolve");
    },
    function () {
     console.log("2nd reject");
    }
   );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Adding to RGraham: If you want the 2nd promise to get rejected too, return `$q.reject()`. The reason for this initially odd behaviour is that your 1st rejection function may be able to correct the error and continue normally with the chained promise. Also another note: if you *omit* the 1st rejection handler, then the second promise is auto-rejected.

Comment: see also: [Promise's second .then() not failing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23943322/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed the next line of the docs:

> This method *returns a new promise* which is resolved or rejected via
>   the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback.

If you want the next chain to be the result of the same promise for whatever reason, return deferred.promise from inside your handler.

```
// This will always trigger the reject callback
deferred.promise.then(function () {
        console.log("1st resolove");
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    function () {
        console.log("1st reject");
        return deferred.promise;
    }
)
```

If you want to return either the success/failed callback, depending on the result of the first, `return $q.when()` inside your success and `return $q.reject()` inside your failure:

```
deferred.promise.then(function () {
        console.log("1st resolove");
        return $q.when();
    },
    function () {
        console.log("1st reject");
        return $q.reject();
    }
).then(function () {
        console.log("2nd resolve");
    },
    function () {
        console.log("2nd reject");
    }
);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/53qcnrx3/)